# Laravel Datatables

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, datatables

I am trying to use server side processing for my datatable but it just doesn't work when you use the pagination.  It reads processing, but does nothing. It pops up with  requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0

```
  $('#load').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "{{ url('api/testing')}}","columns": [
     { "data": "id" },
     { "data": "title" }
    ],
    "deferLoading": 20
  });
```

TABLE

```
 <table id="load">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Booking ID</th>
                <th>Booking Title</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
           @foreach($bookings as $booking)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $booking->id }} </td>
                <td>{{ $booking->title }}</td>
               </tr>
           @endforeach
      </tbody>
</table>
```

JSON

```
{
    data: [
        {
        id: 1,
        title: "Title 1"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        title: "A Meeting"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        title: "Another title"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got datatables to work in my project:

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('admin.requester.index');
}
```

**View:**

header:
    `<link href="\css/plugins/datatables/customDT.css" rel="stylesheet">`

table:

```
<table id="requesters" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ trans('admin/user.show.id') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('admin/user.show.first_name') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('admin/user.show.last_name') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('admin/user.show.email') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('admin/user.show.created_at') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('admin/user.show.confirmed') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('admin/admin.url.actions') }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

script: `<script src="\js\plugins\dataTables\customDT.js"></script>`

**CSS file:**

```
#requesters {
 margin: 0 auto;
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**JS file:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#requesters').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "requesters/ajax",
    "autoWidth": false,
    "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [
            { 'sWidth': '40px' },
            { 'sWidth': '80px', 'sClass': 'center' },
            { 'sWidth': '80px', 'sClass': 'center' },
            { 'sWidth': '70px', 'sClass': 'center' },
            { 'sWidth': '80px', 'sClass': 'center' },
            { 'sWidth': '35px', 'sClass': 'center' },
            { 'sWidth': '55px', 'sClass': 'center' }
        ],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});

});
```

^ Ajax requests to requesters/ajax <- goes to ajax_index in controller:

`Route::get('requesters/ajax', ['uses' => 'admin\RequesterController@index_ajax']);`

**Controller:**

```
public function index_ajax()
{
    $requesters = User::select($this->ajax_columns)->where('user_role_id', '=', REQUESTER_ROLE_ID);

    return Datatables::of($requesters)
        ->add_column('show', '{{ HTML::actions(\'requester\', $id) }}')
        ->make();
}

private $ajax_columns = [
    'id', 
    'first_name', 
    'last_name', 
    'email', 
    'created_at', 
    'confirmed'
];
```

No ->get() or ->paginate(), datatables handles the rest.